# CSS3 animation not working after deployment

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have some jquery that executes and adds a class to a div. This class has a style that runs an animation.
Works perfectly on my local machine via IE (not great on Chrome but kind of) and fine on Firefox, but when I publish it stops animating in IE but not Chrome or Firefox. I have set my privacy and security settings as low as poss in IE so not sure what it is.

Anyone know why?Fairly new to CSS animations - I am probably not doing it the best way. I am trying to animate the form in a kind of "sending" way. My main issue is it not running in IE but only on published site. Second lesser issue is that it doesn't work as well on Chrome as it does on the other 2 - what can I do to change that?

Here is my markup:

```
<form id="emailForm" role="form">
<div id="emailDiv">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" id="fg1">
            <label for="emailSubject">Subject</label>
            <input id="emailSubject" placeholder="Enter Subject" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="fg2">
            <label for="emailMessage">Message</label>
            <textarea id="emailMessage" placeholder="Enter Message" class="form-control" rows="20"></textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<div class="form-group" id="fg3">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="button" value="Send" id="emailSubmit" onclick="javascript: SendPlayerEmail();" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<div id="emailSent" style="display:none">
    <span>Email sent :o)</span>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EmailDto() {
    return {
        subject: $('#emailSubject').val(),
        body: $('#emailMessage').val()
    };
}


function SendPlayerEmail() {
    //debugger;
    var d = JSON.stringify(new EmailDto());
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (x, ss) {
            $('#emailSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        url: rootUrl + 'api/PlayerGame/SendEmail',// "/api/PlayerGame/GetGames",
        data:d,
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
    $.when(xhr).done(function (data) {
        $('#emailDiv').one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function (e) {
            HideEmail();
        })
        $('#emailDiv').addClass('sendEmail');
    });
    $.when(xhr).fail(function (response) {
        alert('There was a problem - sorry. Use the contact page.');
        alert(response.responseText);
        $('#emailSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    })

}

function AfterEmailSend() {
    $('#emailDiv').fadeOut(function () {
        $('#emailSent').slideDown();
    });
}
function HideEmail() {
    //debugger;
    AfterEmailSend();
}


</script>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes demo {
50% {

-webkit-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
}

100% {

-webkit-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes demo {
50% {
-moz-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
}
100% {
-moz-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
}

@-ms-keyframes demo {
50% {
-ms-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
}
100% {
-ms-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
}

@-o-keyframes demo {
50% {
-o-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
}
100% {
-o-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
}

@keyframes demo {
50% {
-webkit-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
-o-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
-moz-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
-ms-transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
transform:translate(50%,0) scale(0.7,0.7);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
-o-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
-moz-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
-ms-transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
transform:translate(60%,-100%) scale(0.5,0.5);
height:0;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
}
}

div.sendEmail {
-webkit-animation-name: demo;
-webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-ms-animation-name: demo;
-ms-animation-duration: 900ms;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-name: demo;
-moz-animation-duration: 900ms;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-name: demo;
animation-duration: 900ms;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Works fine from VS2013 (IIS Express) but when published, even locally to my own machine, it does not work for IE11 but still works the same for the other 2. All relevant files seem to be published - can't see anything missing

When I run the locally published version, the ajax stuff works but the animation doesn't take place. If I then click back into the textarea, then I get the fadeOut and slideDown but not the animation. If I don't click anything then it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: First make sure your published domain is not in compatibility mode or the server is not added an X-UA-Compatible header for a legacy IE version. Next if you are using a bundle and minification process (and you should) make sure it is not making a syntax error in your CSS. I know one of the minifiers can mess up media queries, can't recall which one off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 0):

found this: http://www.markskowrondesign.com/blog/are-your-css3-animations-broken-in-ie10-and-ie11/

When I put my keyframes in a separate css and put them at the top and bundled them separately (because I am using MVC), it worked fine.

Still don't know why Chrome doesn't render as well as the other 2

cheers